# Microsoft Reporting Services 2008- Multi-Value Parameter- New Page

Tags: reporting-services, group-by, parameter-passing, page-break, multivalue

I am creating a report where the parameter selection = customer_name and the report is one page and has 5 tablix relating to the customer. What my team would like is to be able to select more than one customer at a time to save time; however they want a separate page per customer_name. Can this be done with multi-value parameter and if so, how do I group so that the data does not comingle with each other?

Ex.
ABC Customer
RentTablix
ExpenseTablix
PAGE BREAK
EFG Customer
RentTablix
ExpenseTablix

I am over thinking this??? Please help ;-)

Comment: Are you using a stored procedure or a SQL query?

Answer (score 0):

On the report parameter enable the multi-select option. Pass this through to your reporting procs ensuring it's handled properly (I think it's a comma seperated list). In the report add a list control and put all the tablix control into the list area. Set the grouping on the list region to be base on customer and specify a page break on change of customer in the list control.